# Creating a new column of character values based on numeric value condition in R?

Tags: r

How do I create a new column of character values based on  numeric value that are to be assigned the following names: 0 = user, 1 = admin, 2 = sponsor

```
dat1 
       one  two three
1     Bob    0  
2     Mary   0  
3 restaurant 2  
4   company  1
```

so based on those names, how do I get to this:

```
dat1 
       one  two three
1     Bob    0  user
2     Mary   0  user
3 restaurant 2  sponsor
4   company  1  admin

dat1 <- data.frame(one=c("Bob", "Mary", "restaurant", "company"), two=c("0","0", "2", "1"))
```

And yes I know how simply create them via:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(one=c("Bob", "Mary", "restaurant", "company"), two=c("0","0", "2", "1"), three=c("user", "user", "sponsor", "admin"))
```

But what's the function that would preform the task?
So under column three, based on the corresponding row under column two, I want 0 = user, 1 = admin, 2 = sponsor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `two` column is a factor.  The integer representations of `dat1$two` as a factor are 1 for 0, 2 for 1, and 3 for 2.  So if we use it as an index vector on a character vector of what we want to to get, we can expand the vector accordingly.

```
dat1$three <- c("user", "admin", "sponsor")[dat1$two]
dat1
#          one two   three
# 1        Bob   0    user
# 2       Mary   0    user
# 3 restaurant   2 sponsor
# 4    company   1   admin
```

If you don't already have a factor in the `two` column, you can make it into one with the following.

```
dat1$three <- c("user", "admin", "sponsor")[as.factor(dat1$two)]
```

These both create a new character column.

**Update:** As Frank mentions, the more idiomatic method would be to simply factor the `two` column and apply different labels.

```
dat1$three <- factor(dat1$two, labels = c("user", "admin", "sponsor"))
```

This creates a new factor column.